# Do gravitational forces act on parallel moving bodies?

Tags: gravity

I need this information to check whether I can use gravitation as a metaphor in a talk. How does gravitational forces differ when two objects are moving in parallel versus they are moving towards each other? What is happening in the former scenario? Are they staying in parallel  for as long as no other force applies?
I hope so much that this is a very easy question for most of you. Probably I just don't have the right vocabulary to google it correctly.

Thanks so much in advance for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have two stationary objects and no forces. They don't move. Suppose you run by the same two objects. Now they move in parallel lines.

Now add gravity. The stationary objects attract each other. They move toward each other and collide.

If you run by them, they move in parabolic curves instead of straight lines.

Answer (score 0):

Gravitational forces don't depend on the motion of objects (except in extreme situations described in general relativity. If there was any such thing as a perfectly uniform gravitational field then uniform (parallel) relative motions would be maintained. This is Einstein's principle of equivalence, but it only applies in a locality. Here is a figure from my [second book](https://www.troubador.co.uk/bookshop/computing-science-education/light-after-dark-ii/)

[image: tidal forces]

It shows that, in the absence of active forces, objects do not necessarily remain on parallel paths.